# connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0 on meteor startup

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, connect, momentjs

So, I keep getting this error on starting up Meteor.

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
```

It started happening after I added the moment package, I removed it but still got the error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is likely a warning & not an error. Its not likely from Meteor or Moment, but another package you might have.

It should not stop your app from starting up/working.

There are a lot of packages that use connect, such as iron-router. Its best to just wait for the package maintainer to update the code so the warning is removed.

Comment: I am receiving the same error when i enter 'node app' in the cmd. It halts the command and throws that error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you go the website that the warning told you to go to?

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0

It explains in detail what is going on, and how to fix it.

> Note that if you're currently using connect.bodyParser(), you will still get the deprecation >warning for multipart. For now, you can ignore it since you should only see the warning message once at start up. If you want to avoid any warning messages, do this instead (which is what connect.bodyParser() will be in 3.0):

```
app.use(connect.urlencoded())
app.use(connect.json())
```

I was using express.bodyParser(), so in my solution I used

```
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.json())
```

and it worked fine. No more warnings.